# Access subclass in codeigniter 3.0.1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I will extend the controller based of login typical, so I create on application directory like this:

```
core
 -MY_Controller
 -public controller
```

**MY_Controller**

```
<?php
    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {

       public function __construct()
       {
          parent::__construct();
       }
    }
```

**public controller**

```
<?php

  class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller
  {
     //Some Logic here
     public $layout = 'layout';
  }
```

Now, time to use those things.
I write on application/route `$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';`

So, the controll that named `Home` would be like this :

```
<?php
  class Home extends Public_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('public/home');
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, it gives me error like this :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Public_Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\egi\application\controllers\Home.php on line 5
```

Why I can not to extends the sub class ?

**NOTE**
But if I extends from MY_Controller, its success

```
  <?php
     class Home extends MY_Controller {
       public function index() {
         $this->load->view('public/home');
    }
}
```

Any help it so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of the following ways.

- Have a file named Public_controller in "application/core" & include that file in your application/core/MY_Controller.php file.
- Define Public_Controller inside MY_Controller file which is autoloaded by default which means you'd end up with something like this.

File: application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct () {
         parent::__construct();
   }
}

class Public_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct () {
         parent::__construct();
   }
}
```